# View from the bottom to half screen

Tags: android

I'd like to have a View that come from bottom with Animation to fill half screen. In that View I would have lots of ImageButtons.
I could program the animation from bottom to half screen but after that my view is filling all screen.

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

xml code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen_dashboard" style="@style/drawer"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
(...)
<TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:onClick="slideUpDown" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:onClick="slideUpDown" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Java Code:

```
public void slideUpDown(final View view) {

        if (!isPanelShown()) {
            // Show the panel
            Animation bottomUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.bottom_up);
            hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomUp);

            hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            // Hide the Panel
            Animation bottomDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.animator.bottom_down);

            hiddenPanel.startAnimation(bottomDown);
            hiddenPanel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private boolean isPanelShown() {
        return hiddenPanel.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
    }
```

Does anyone know what can I do for my view just fill half screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use bottom sheet dialog fragment. This will animate from bottom & take the required size of the fragment from bottom by default. You don't need to write extra code for animation.

[BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialogFragment)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 quick solutions that can fit your needs:

1) [BottomSheet](https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066). You can configure the height of this view in expanded state by using  `app:behavior_peekHeight`.

2) [MotionLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/motion/MotionLayout). In this case you will be able to configure beautifull transition between states. Moreover view that above bottom view could be animated to transit with bottom view. 
But it is still in alpha. So it can contain bugs and api can be changed significantly in future releases.